# Pyramid of hopelessness

Tags: number-sequence

Here are the numbers.... What'cha gonna do? 
(try and solve it...duh)

```
                                   1
                               1       1
                               2       1
                           1   2       1    1
                        1    1   1   2    2    1
                      ????????????????????????????
```